# how to traverse a queue in java

Tags: java, android, concurrency

I have a `ThreadPoolExecutor` that fulfils my `DownloadTask implements Runnable{private String taskId...` tasks and I need to have possibility in any time to get a define task from the `ThreadPoolExecutor` queue, for example, using a task id:

```
mDownloadTasksPool.getQueue();
```

what is the best way to travesre a queue and to get a define element?

It's possible to have a list with all duplicates tasks but it looks not very elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass your Runnables to provide a getter for taskID (if that's your key). Create a concurrent map, mapping your taskID to the Runnable that you put in the queue. Subclass your ThreadPoolExecutor. In beforeExecute, you remove the current task from that map since it's not in the queue anymore. You may want to cast the Runnable to your custom class to use that taskID getter.

Comment: I don't want to use a separate collection object, i want to do it only using ThreadPoolExecutor with it's BlockingQueue.

Comment: well, in that case you will have to traverse the whole queue everytime you want to find a task. This queue will be used by the TPE too, but thankfully, the iterators of both LinkedlockingQueue and ArrayBlockingQueue are weakly consistent, and will not throw ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: `ThreadPoolExecutor` does not have _it's_ `BlockingQueue` per se. You must supply your own queue in the constructor. Most multithreading TPEs offered by `Executors` use LinkedBlockingQueues.